# Realizar Update no PostgreSQL pelo PgAdmin sem comando SQL e sim pela Interface

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Preciso alterar determinados dados do meu banco `PostgreSQL` pelo `PgAdmin` porém gostaria que fosse direto pela interface do `PgAdmin` e não através de comandos SQL, isso é possível. Por exemplo quando quero criar uma nova coluna em alguma tabela,  a própria interface me disponibiliza isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procurei mas encontrei apenas modos de fazer **Update** através de comandos SQL e gostaria de saber se há alguma possibilidade de fazer isso de alguma forma mais fácil.

Tentativa de alterar pela interface do pgAdmin4:

**Passo 01:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Passo 02:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Passo 03:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém mesmo assim não consegui editar os registros.

Comment: Sim é possível, clica com o botão direito em cima da tabela desejada vai em properties e depois na aba columns.

Comment: @rray Alterar a coluna eu já sabia que era possível, minha necessidade é conseguir alterar os dados salvos na tabela sem que seja por meio de comandos SQL

Comment: aaah entendi, vc quer alterar individualmente? isso dá agora se for mais de um registro não conheço

Comment: Digamos que eu de o comando `Select * from ` em uma table, ele me traz todos os registros dessa tabela, o que eu necessito é, digamos que eu queira alterar determinado registro, eu clique em cima desse registro e altere sua informação ali direto, sem a necessidade de dar o comando `update`

Comment: No pgAdmin3 eu faria assim, clica no nome da tabela vai na opção de exibir dados ( não lembro o nome exatao) no topo vai ter um botão de filtro lá coloque o seu where dê um filtrar ai pode alterar os valores clicando nas celulas.

Comment: Eu faço um `Select` normal nesse filtro? **select * from public.Table where parâmetro**

Comment: Na janela que abrir vc coloca se não me engano só as condições por exemplo `id = 20 and ativo = true` não vai select nem where só as condi~ções.

Comment: Estou com o PgAdmin4 nele essa opção de clicar em cima das celulas e alterar não tem disponível

Comment: Vou fazer uns testes depois no pgAdmin4.

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui deu certo no pgAdmin4, as celulas ficaram editaveis ( usei a opção `view data > view filtred data`) depois clica no icone do disquete para salvar as modificações. Se quiser ver como é no pgAdmin3 veja [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31872888/1342547)

Comment: @rray Tentei fazer como você sugeriu mas não consegui alterar os registros, editei a minha pergunta com o passo a passo de como  tentei para que você pudesse ver como fiz. Se puder daqui a pouco postar uma resposta de como você fez para alterar os registros pela interface do pgAdmin4, daqui a pouco será melhor

Comment: Tem chave primária essa tabela?

Comment: @rray Essa não tem

Comment: Então deve ser por isso, nas tabelas que tem chave primária funciona o procedimento?

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou normalmente

Comment: Eu não sei pq essa tabela não tem uma chave primária :P mas deveria ter uma.

Comment: Já estou alterando isso, na verdade esse banco é um legado, estou adicionando nas tabelas as Chaves primarias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após o auxílio do usuário @rray♦ consegui resolver o problema, o erro estava em minhas tabelas que não tinham `primary key` e por esse motivo não permitia alterar os registros direto pela interface do pgAdmin4